# Laravel blade method latest doesn´t exist on user model

Tags: php, laravel, methods, laravel-blade

In my user model (`App\User.php`), I declare following relationship:

```
public function actionables() {
  return $this->hasMany(Actionable::class, 'owner_id', 'id');
}
```

In my migration scheme for the actionables table, I specify following foreign key:

```
$table->foreign('owner_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

When I call

```
{{ auth()->user()->actionables->where('act_type', 'order')->latest()->content }}
```

In a blade view, I get following error message:

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::latest does not exist.
```

I´ve tried using `->get()` and using other way´s of accessing the user model (`Auth::user`), but nothing has solved the problem so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distinction that the other answers are glossing over is using the query builder vs using a collection. When you call the relationship using a property Eloquent will fetch all the results then return a collection (which is basically just a beefed up array). So when you do

```
auth()->user()->actionables
```

Laravel executes the SQL Query then returns **all** the results as a collection.

```
SELECT * FROM actionables WHERE owner_id = ?
```

The collection class has a `where` method that functions similarly to the query builder method, but it's important to realize that it's performing the search in PHP not SQL because the query has already been executed and can't be changed anymore. `latest()` exists on the query builder, but not the collection which is where your error is coming from.

To leverage the relationship in the query builder you need to call the relationship as a function. `user()->actionables()`

```
auth()->user()->actionables()->where('act_type', 'order')->latest()->first()
```

The above will execute the SQL query then return just the record you're looking for.

```
SELECT * FROM actionables WHERE act_type = order AND WHERE owner_id = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks, you were the only one here explaining the cause of the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the query builder `actionables()` not the collection `actionables`, i.e:

```
{{ auth()->user()->actionables()->where('act_type', 'order')->latest()->first()->content }}
```

Comment: Using this, `latest()` will be a query builder instance and the `content` property won't exist. You need to chain `first()` or something to run the query and get results for this to work.

Comment: You are right @travis-britz I forgot `first()` to retrieve a single record, I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`latest` not exist not within `Collection` methods.

to get the last element of your database query you should apply this query:

*Note that you should have `created_at` within the `Actionable`  table.

```
auth()->user()->actionables()->where('act_type', 'order')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first()->content
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be `->last()` not `->latest()`

```
{{ auth()->user()->actionables->where('act_type', 'order')->last()->content ?? ""}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Collection does not have the latest method, it's the query builder that has that method.

Try last instead.

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#available-methods